# stop or kill thread in python

Tags: python, django, multithreading

I am creating a function that creates threads.

if I recall the function running threads should be terminated.

and new threads should be created.

```
def callme():
    t1 = thread(target=somefunction, args=(,))
    t2 = thread(target=somefunction, args=(,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()

def somefunction():
    for i in range(10000000):
        print(i)

callme() #callme1
sleep(2)
callme() #callme2
```

if I callme1 than 2 threads should be created
after 2 seconds I call callme2 then, threads of callme1 should be killed or stopped.

and 2 threads of callme2 runs

I am using some kind of this technique in Django if I fetch the URL than some view function calls,  which contains these types of thread structures.

Comment: As things are, `callme` will only return after both threads stop. I'm not sure what you're actually trying to do here. Can you show us an actual example from your Django code?

Comment: if someone clicks the button from UI then it will create a large file using thread. for creating this file I am using 1 view. view function manages all threads and similar structures of callme(). if user clicks multiple times then the view function also calls multiple times, just like callme() callme() callme().  i want to terminate the thread if the view function recalls.

Comment: Right - that wouldn't work in a multiprocess server environment anyway. If you want a robust background work system, you'll need to look into e.g. rq or celery.